# How to set number of cell in section collection view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a collection view with more sections, so how to set the number of cell in section in collection view. Thank for help

Comment: What have you tried? It is just the same as for a UITableView. What isn't working for you?

Answer (score 1):

```
// Hi Please fallow this code it may help you

// This collectionView delegate method defined number of section we need

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 2;
}

/* This collectionView delegate method for define number of cell need to return in section
 */

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0)
    {
        return 10;
    }
    else
    {
        return 20;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method:

– `numberOfItemsInSection`:

Or you can refer:

> https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012177-CH1-DontLinkElementID_5

for `UICollectionView` details...